# Проблема распознавания табличных данных

Tags: php, mysql

В mysql есть пользователь, но код его не видит.
Как я понял, проблема в том что переменные $login и $password не правильно распознают таблицу.

```
include('db.php');

//---------------проблема здесь---------------
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$count = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = "$login" AND `password` = "$password"');
//--------------------------------------------

if( mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    echo 'not found';
} else
{ //при нахождении пользователя
    echo "hi " . $login;
}
```

страница с запросом логина:

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>

<form method="POST" action="/test_2.php">
    <input type='text' placeholder="login_input" name='login'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="password_input" name='password'>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<?php
```

коннект с субд:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'test_db');

if( $connection == false )
{
    echo 'not found';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}?>
```

Comment: У вас неверно расставлены кавычки в запросе. Поставьте сначала двойные, а внутри запроса одинарные

Comment: А лучше вообще конкатенацией делайте - так точно ни с чем не запутаетесь.

Comment: Сделайте вывод данных POST и проверьте что туда приходит. Пока что я вижу что у вас в HTML форме используются одинарные кавычки вместо стандартных двойных.

Comment: больше всего в таких вопросах поражают комментаторы. @VladimirGonchar во-первых, конкатенация как раз совсем путает новичеков типа вас и автора вопроса. там кавычек в миллион раз больше получается. Не говоря уже о том что в запросе *вообще не должно быть никаких кавычек и переменных*.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov и что?

Comment: @ali смотри ответ на вопрос который я прикрепил сверху. В твоем коде неправильно почти всё. Надо переписать и регистрацию, и авторизацию

Comment: @Ипатьев, и имя им - Легион.

Comment: @Ипатьев Как раз конкатенация - это нормальный вариант. Пусть привыкает сразу, а не ловит потом приколы в виде "ой, а что это у меня переменная просто текстом вывелась". Сложность в чём? Поставить подсветку в редакторе? Понятное дело, что подстановка переменных в sql - это баян, и что скулю можно получить очень просто.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar поверь, выучить какие кавычки за что отвечают не так сложно, как тебе кажется :) Не надо бояться интерполяции.